# How to add Jquery Confirmation Modal

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I was trying to delete a data from database using jquery and the following script helped me to do so. Now I want to show a jquery confirmation modal(YES: NO) before it finally goes for deleting it. I went through some tutorials to learn how to do that but I couldn't make those work for me

Please kindly show me how to add the confirmation modal.

Thanks

```
<script>

 $(function(){ // added
             $('a.delete').click(function(){
                var a_href = $(this).attr('href'); 
     $.ajax({

     type: "POST",
     url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>batchlist/delete",
     data: "id="+a_href,
     success: function(server_response){

               if(server_response == '1')
                            { alert('MSG');}  else {$("#trid_"+a_href).hide('slow'); }

                                    }               

   });  //$.ajax ends here

                return false
    });//.click function ends here
  }); // function ends here         


 </script
```

This is my delete anchor

```
<a href="<?php echo $row['studentid']; ?>" title="Delete" class="delete" ><img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>support/images/icons/cross.png" alt="Delete" /></a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need jQuery to do this. Javascript will do this just lovelyly:

```
if (confirm("Are you sure you want to contiune with this request?")) {
     //Do stuff
}
```

Simple :)

Comment: is there any way to add some styles (CSS) to your solution. It doesn't look good...:) thanks

Comment: Sadly the style is browser sepsific. If you were going to introduce a styled version i would either dynamically add in a new element and just have a link to the delete in there. Remove that once the user has clicked it. Or look at http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/ and put my link in there and then in the success of your ajax i would close this box. This way you know the box will only disappear if the request was successful.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this is with basic javascript.

Right before the ajax call, put this

```
if(!confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?') {
    return false;
}
```

So if they decline, it just doesn't bother with the ajax.

Answer (score 0):

I find it convinient to use jquery widget for modal dialog, and handle delete/cancel buttons.

```
(function ($) {
        $.widget('my.confirmDialog', {
            options: {
                url: null,
                elements: null,
                postParamName: 'id',
                afterDelete: null
            },
            _create: function () {
                var that = this;
                var options = that.options;
                that.element.dialog({
                    resizable: false,
                    autoOpen: false,
                    modal: true,
                    buttons: {
                        "Delete": function (e, ui) {
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                            $.post(options.url, that.postData, function (resp) {
                                that._trigger('afterDelete', e, resp);
                            });
                        },
                        "Cancel": function () {
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                        }
                    }
                });
                options.elements.live('click', function (event, ui) {
                    that.askConfirmation(this);
                });
            },
            askConfirmation: function (askElem) {
                var that = this;

                var confirmationText = $(askElem).attr("data-confirmation");
                that.element.text(confirmationText);

                var postData = {};
                postData[that.options.postParamName] = $(askElem).attr("data-value");
                that.postData = postData;

                that.element.dialog("open");
            },
            destroy: function () {
                this.element.dialog("destroy");
                $.Widget.prototype.destroy.apply(this, arguments);
            }

        });

    } (jQuery));
```

usage is really simple, you just create div for confirmation dialog:

```
<div title="Delete confirmation" id="sampleDeleteConfirmation"
    style="display: none;">
</div>
```

and apply widget to this div, passing the elements that should trigger confirmation dialog show:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#sampleDeleteConfirmation").confirmDialog({
            url: '/DeleteUrl',
            postParamName: 'canChangeThisIfNeeded',
            elements: $(".confirmThis"),
            afterDelete: function (event, response) {
                //callback after delete
            }
        });

    });
```

also for convinience i use data- attributes on buttons that show modal dialog to modify text and pass value for post to delete action.

```
          <button type="button" class="confirmThis" data-value="123" data-confirmation="Delete item 123?">
                Delete
           </button>
          <button type="button" class="confirmThis" data-value="567" data-confirmation="Delete item 567?">
                Delete
           </button>
```

and thats all )